# How to Start a Service and Stop Rest of the Similar Services Based on a Keyword in the Service Name from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have couple are more services that have same naming convention example is below. I am looking for a way to write a PowerShell script where it should check the service name and make sure the service is running if not start the service and rest of the services should be stopped. When the service is started it should output that service has started. My current script only run the service if it's not already running. Appreciate any help here.

Example:
srvx1,
srvx2,
srvx3,
srvx4,
and so on...

```
$ServiceName = 'srvx3'
$arrService = Get - Service - Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status - ne 'Running') {

    Start - Service $ServiceName
    write - host $arrService.status
    write - host 'Service starting'
    Start - Sleep - seconds 60
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status - eq 'Running') {
        Write - Host 'Service is now Running'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the parameter `-name` of the cmdlet `get-service` supports *, so you can do:

```
$ServiceName = 'srvx*'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
```

Now you have all services where the name starts with srv in the array `$arrayService`.

If you want to monitor the service and once it goes down you want to start it you should set the condition in the while loop to -eq and not -ne, because you want the while loop to execute until the service goes down... otherwise it exit because the service is running and will never start it, if it goes down:

```
#pick specific service out of list of all services
$service = ($arrService | ?{$_.name -eq  'srvx3'})
while ($service.Status -eq 'Running'){
    Start-Sleep -seconds 60
    #refresh status of all services
    $arrService.Refresh()
    If ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped'){
        try {
            $null = $service.start()
            $null = $service.Refresh()
            write-host $service.name $service.status
        }
        Catch {
            write-error "failed to start service $($service.name) - Exception: $_"
            #exit as unable to start service
            return
        }
        #stop all other services if they are running
        ($arrService | ?{$_.name -ne $service.name -and $_.status -eq 'Running'}).Stop()
    }
}
```

Hopefully I did understand you corretly, currently the script would monitor the status of a specific service and if this one goes down the script would start it and STOP all other services which name starts with the defined pattern. Also it would continuosly monitor the service and even continue to do so if it did start the service, it only exit the while loop if it fails to start the service.